# How to track the code coverage progress in sonarqube community edition Version 7.9.3 for a specific time period

Tags: sonarqube, code-coverage

Currently we are using the sonarqube community edition 7.9.3, we have multiple projects on sonar, we want to track the code coverage progress(progress in a sprint) in single place.Can someone enlighten me on how to achieve this?